# Hide Button only on External/Affiliate Product Page / NOT in shop

Tags: php, woocommerce

**I would like to hide all buttons only for Eternal/Affiliate and only on the produce page**

**TLDR**

On my site I have a few Pricing tables where the customer can select the appropriate one and then add that item to the cart.

The issue is trying to make an empty product where you cannot purchase it but the pricing table is in the description. So I had to user Eternal/Affiliate product. Which works perfectly as the URL is the product page itself which is great for the shop.

The issue is on the product page you can see a button which says add to cart.

I would like to hide this button only for Eternal/Affiliate and only on the produce page.

You see I already have this code below but obviously I do not want to restrict it to ID numbers and variable products.

**Update**

so the code below works but if I put a URL link in on the product page then it does not work. Unfortunately now a little bit stumped.

What would be great is if I could remove the button and replace it with some text for example please read below.

```
 function woocommerce_add_aff_link(){
  $product = wc_get_product(get_the_ID());
  if ($product->is_type('external'))
    echo '<a href="' .
         $product->get_product_url() .
         '" class="woocommerce-LoopProductImage-link">';
}
```

**Update +**

After some digging around I found that it is actually more logical to create a new product however the solution below works perfectly:

Reference : https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-how-to-create-a-new-product-type/

Comment: yes I understand that and I have created functions before but this time I'm a little bit baffled on how to approach it.

Comment: This has already been answered for all WooCommerce product types, so you need to target Eternal/Affiliate product type ("external") in an if statement…

Comment: perfect. Thank you for the feedback I will do that.. The issue I had was I was looking for affiliate which is not the right one. Thanks I will get back to you.

Comment: Thank you for that. Now I genuinely mean it you are a top guy. let me just play around with this. I'm determined to figure this one out.

Comment: Okay, this is the where I am now. unfortunately I do not know how to make it ignore if there is a link in the URL on the product page. Thanks

Comment: I have finally answered below…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove add to cart button on single external product pages use the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'remove_external_product_add_to_cart_button', 4 );
function remove_external_product_add_to_cart_button(){
    global $product;
    
    if ( ! is_a($product, 'WC_Product') ) {
        $product = wc_get_product(get_the_ID());
    }

    if ( $product->is_type('external') ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
    } 
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). TIt should work.

Comment: Thank you.. I have accepted this as the correct answer. Also, After a little bit of thinking and research I found that you can naturally create your own product data "https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-how-to-create-a-new-product-type/"

Comment: @Arthor You can also add custom fields to an existing product to make it custom. Adding a new product type is something much more advanced (note that businessbloomer take most of their code from others, so you should avoid this web site).

Comment: I did consider that as an option. I played around with the settings but it was far more advantageous to use a price table as it looks far more elegant. Thank you very much for the support and the lesson learnt!